# MouseCapture prevents all mouse based triggers from firing in WPF

Tags: wpf

I am using CaptureMouse() during a drag and drop operation to make sure I don't miss the MouseUp event, but this seems to prevent any mouse events reaching any other objects on my Canvas. This means that my IsMouseOver based triggers don't work, but I need them to indicate valid locations where the object can be dropped.

Am I doing this wrong, or is there a way of making sure everything on my Canvas still gets mouse events?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are the elements part of the SubTree of your canvas? or outside of the canvas? If they are within then you could probably use the Capture method that takes a [CaptureMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.capturemode(VS.85).aspx).

```
Mouse.Capture(elementToCapture, CaptureMode.SubTree);
```

Alternatively, you should look at the [DragDrop class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dragdrop_members.aspx) and consider using the [Drop event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dragdrop.dropevent.aspx) instead?

Comment: The first option worked, as long as I offset the dragged connection slightly so it wasn't underneath the mouse while it was being dragged. Thanks!